# Openlayers - Change layer visibility by its name

Tags: openlayers, visibility, layer

Is there any way to change a layer's visibility by its name, not by its var name?

```
var mylayer=new Openlayers.Layer.Vector('Layer 1', ...
```

I'd like to change the visibility by using 'Layer 1' and not 'mylayer'

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for getLayersByName of the map class, see [the map docs.](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getLayersByName) This function takes a match parameter which can be  regular expression.

```
var layer=map.getLayersByName('Layer 1');
layer[0].setVisibility(false);
```

or just,

```
map.getLayersByName('Layer 1')[0].setVisibility(false);
```

EDIT: Following comments by the OP, it should be noted that getLayersByName returns an array of matching layers, so it is necessary to index the correct one. Assuming there is only one, then using layer[0], as above, will work.

Comment: You are welcome. If it has helped you, perhaps you could consider accepting it :D

Comment: Sure! Sorry for that, I'm a new user :)

Comment: There is only one detail you missed: 'map.getLayersByName' returns an array, so the way it worked for me was 'layer[0].setVisibility(false)'